# Install qgis2web plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I would like to know how and where I can download qgis2web Plugin.
I use QGIS with 2.10.1 version.

Answer (score 9):

You should install it via `Plugins --> Manage and Install Plugins` and then search for `qgis2web` (see below). (Further details about installing external QGIS plugins can be found [in the offical docs](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html#load-external-plugin).)

The plugin appears in the Web menu.

[image]